# How can I schedule a task with asyncio to run in executor?

Tags: python, threadpool, python-asyncio

I have been using asyncio for concurrency, however I have run into a problem. I have the need to schedule a task with asyncio but it is blocking and so I would like to execute it in an executor using threadpool from concurrent.futures.

I have seen example like this, that schedule tasks:

```
now = loop.time()
loop.call_at(now + 60, callback, arg, loop)
```

and like this that run tasks in executors:

```
blocking_tasks = [
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, blocks)
    for i in range(6)
]
completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(blocking_tasks)
```

But how can I schedule a blocking task to run in executor?

Answer (score 5):

`run_in_executor` returns a future, so you can't use it with `call_at`, which requires an ordinary function. However, you can easily postpone execution using [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep):

```
async def my_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, fn)
    ...

taskobj = loop.create_task(my_task())
```

This has the advantage that the task created by [`create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_task) can be [canceled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) during the sleep. Also, you can return a useful value from `my_task()` and obtain it using `await taskobj`, calling [`taskobj.result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.result), or [`loop.run_until_complete(taskobj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete).

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper like this for this.

```
def run_in_async_loop(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return (await loop.run_in_executor(None, f(*args, **kwargs)))
    return wrapped
```

Comment: Add a `)` to the first `return` line to prevent syntax error.